# Creating Destination Charges with Stripe - ArgumentError - Unsupported argument type: 1 (Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I'm implementing destination charges with fee collection with `stripe`. Below is the code implementation as based on [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee):

```
def create
    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [{
        price_data: {
          currency: "usd",
          product_data: {
            name: "Provider Payment",
          },
         
          unit_amount: 500,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      payment_intent_data: {
        application_fee_amount: 123,
        transfer_data: {
          destination: PetProvider.find(PetOwnerPetProvider.find_by(current_pet_owner.id).pet_provider_id).uid, #pick the current_pet_provider's stripe account id by way of from POPP Table
        },
      },
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: payments_success_url + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      cancel_url: payments_cancel_url,
    })

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js #render create.js.erb
    end
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
  end
```

Essentially, I have a controller, `PaymentsController` that has this `create` method.

I'm getting `ArgumentError - Unsupported argument type: 1 (Integer):` when I click the `Pay` button that I implemented to call this `create` controller action.

Below is how I implemented the button;

```
<%= button_to 'Pay', payments_create_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
```

I'm passing the `uid` which I'm picking from the `database` and passing it in `destination:`
I can't seem to get it working though.

This is `create.js.erb`:

```
const stripe =  Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]%>');
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: '<%= @session.id %>'
})
```

This is the full stack trace;

```
Started POST "/payments/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-07 18:03:03 +0300
Processing by PaymentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"GBNOhDSTNritpjJYcFwwq98GfTRDKegW9RZTq1cTTQr1YHU3pquLi9iIMFPxHHE5IHGyuzJ8xLC116gB1bKb9g=="}
  PetOwner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pet_owners".* FROM "pet_owners" WHERE "pet_owners"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "pet_owners"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 2999)



ArgumentError - Unsupported argument type: 1 (Integer):
  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace when that error appears? Specifically you'd want to know what line of your code it's being thrown from, and then check the values you're passing to that line's call.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I have edited the question to include the Stack Trace

Comment: Thanks @Esseme. Could you specify what code is on `app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:27`? That appears to be the source of the error.

Comment: @taintedzodiac `destination: PetProvider.find(PetOwnerPetProvider.find_by(current_pet_owner.id).pet_provider_id).uid,` is the code on `app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:27`